# How to set conditional breakpoint based on return value of a function using VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, conditional-breakpoint

anyone has any ideas about how to set a conditional breakpoint based on the return value of a function?
For example, set the condition as below:
`wcscmp(this->traceName(), L"site") == 0`
But this does not work in my Visual Studio 2010.
Anyone can help?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I try it with a return value of a function but it does not work.

But you can implement a line in your code and check the bool. Hope that helps.

[image]